# How to change Artist profile image?

Tags: macos, itunes, music

Is there anyway to force/change/reset the profile image that shows up for an Artist in iTunes?

Answer (score 1):

If you've added custom artwork to an Artist, it will replace the individual Album Artwork that iTunes had previously set.

To clear it, you need to clear each affected album - which can be done as a bulk selection, using shift/click to select all its tracks [but doesn't work if you select more than one Album]
then

- Cmd/I to Get Info
- Artwork Tab
- Select the Custom picture
- Delete or Backspace
- OK
- File Menu > Library > Get Album Artwork
  You can do the last step once only, after resetting all the tracks you need to clear the Custom picture from.

Answer (score 1):

No, when there are artist photos, they are downloaded from the iTunes Store. You can't change them.

Comment: Well, they do seem to change as I add albums to iTunes, I can't quite figure it out but it seems that the latest album I add becomes the cover art for the "artist".